# Pylint: Avoid checking INSIDE DOCSTRINGS (global directive / rcfile)

Tags: python, pylint, static-code-analysis

Consider this *piece of code*:

```
def test():
    """This line is longer than 80 chars, but, for me this is ok inside a DOCSTRING,
    this one is shorter.
    """

    if 'This is toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo longggggggggggggggggggggggg':
        print 'True'
```

`pylint` output:

```
C:  5, 0: Line too long (84/80) (line-too-long)
C:  9, 0: Line too long (83/80) (line-too-long)
```

Is there any *directive* avaliable (`rcfile`) to exclude **ONLY** `DOCSTRINGS` from `pylint` checker?

A *multiline* `regex` for `ignore-long-lines` (**Thanks** *@fredtantini*) seems to be ignored.

Surrounding *docstrings* with `# pylint: dis/enable=line-too-long` (**Thanks** *@Evert*) will cause the required effect, however, I'm looking for a **global directive** to make the *trick*.

Comment: Did you check if `ignore-long-lines` takes a multiline regexp?

Comment: I guess you could surround docstrings with `# pylint: dis/enable=line-too-long` comment, but that's no fun nor pretty.

Comment: There might not be any more options, see the `def check_lines(self, lines, i):` source in `format.py`. It might be possible to write a plugin to override that.

Comment: You are free to have as long docstrings as you want. I think docstrings are more readable if you follow the PEP8 recommandation that docstrings/comments should be maximum 72 characters. As far as I know pylint doesn't distingush between code and comments when checking line length. You can set a global 
max-line-length and that's it.

http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#id3

Comment: @simonzack followed your initial comment and posted an answer (this is crazy, I know) :) Thank you!

Comment: This would be a useful feature for when you are copy/pasting in output from another source and have no choice of line length.

Comment: Although this does not directly answer the question, if you need a tool that checks line-length while ignoring docstrings, you can use `flake8`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the thing you are asking about is **not configurable at all**. Moreover, according to the [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.
>
> For flowing long blocks of text with fewer structural restrictions
>   (docstrings or comments), the line length should be limited to **72 characters**.

That said, let's analyze [the source code](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/src) and see if we can come up with a solution. The checker which is responsible for checking the line length is called a [`FormatChecker`](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/src/2ac93fac800c2bd98dcef479e8a94fed52e6153b/checkers/format.py?at=default#cl-397) - it also checks for indentation and unauthorized code constructions.

The are two relevant methods we are interested in:

- [`check_lines()`](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/src/2ac93fac800c2bd98dcef479e8a94fed52e6153b/checkers/format.py?at=default#cl-908)
- [`new_line()`](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/src/2ac93fac800c2bd98dcef479e8a94fed52e6153b/checkers/format.py?at=default#cl-462) (it is calling `check_lines`)

As you can see the "Line too long" error message is being added here:

```
if len(line) > max_chars and not ignore_long_line.search(line):
    self.add_message('line-too-long', line=i, args=(len(line), max_chars))
```

`ignore_long_line` here refers to the `ignore-long-lines` regular expression setting, which, by default, equals to `^\s*(# )?<?https?://\S+>?$` - which would help in case there are http links inside the (doc)string - no error would be thrown.

In other words, there is only `ignore-long-lines` setting that can prevent pylint from applying the "too long line" check.

Also note the interesting fact: the `pylint` code-quality check utility has this misleading docstring:

```
def check_lines(self, lines, i):
    """check lines have less than a maximum number of characters
    """
```

while the method also checks for `missing-final-newline` and `trailing-whitespace`. This is something you would never catch statically - human error which can be noticed and fixed by a human only.

---

I don't like the following proposal, but we can *monkey-patch the `FormatChecker` on the fly*.

Create a script called "checker.py" and put it on `PYTHONPATH`. Here we are redefining the `new_line()` method and adding a "token type" check - not letting the checker call the `check_lines()` method if this is a comment or a string (docstring). Then, in the `register()` function we are overriding the built-in `FormatChecker`'s `new_line()` with ours:

```
import tokenize
from pylint.checkers.format import FormatChecker, _last_token_on_line_is, _JUNK_TOKENS
import new


class MyFormatChecker(object):
    def new_line(self, tokens, line_end, line_start):
        if _last_token_on_line_is(tokens, line_end, ';'):
            self.add_message('unnecessary-semicolon', line=tokens.start_line(line_end))

        line_num = tokens.start_line(line_start)
        line = tokens.line(line_start)

        token_type = tokens.type(line_start)
        if token_type not in _JUNK_TOKENS:
            self._lines[line_num] = line.split('\n')[0]

        if token_type not in (tokenize.COMMENT, tokenize.STRING):
            self.check_lines(line, line_num)


def register(linter):
    format_checker = linter._checkers['format'][0]
    format_checker.new_line = new.instancemethod(MyFormatChecker.new_line.im_func, format_checker,
                                                 FormatChecker.__class__)
```

Run `pylint` with `--load-plugins` command-line argument:

```
$ pylint --load-plugins checker script.py
```

Demo:

- without the plugin

  ```
  $ pylint script.py 
  C:  2, 0: Line too long (85/79) (line-too-long)
  C:  6, 0: Line too long (83/79) (line-too-long)
  C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
  ```
- with the plugin (no complains about the docstring)

  ```
  $ pylint --load-plugins=checker script.py 
  C:  6, 0: Line too long (83/79) (line-too-long)
  C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
  ```

where `script.py` contains:

```
def test():
    """This line is longer than 80 chars, but , for me this is ok inside a DOCSTRING,
    this one is shorter.
    """

    if 'This is toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo longggggggggggggggggggggggg':
        print 'True'
```

There are few notes that have to be mentioned:

- this is too complicated, fragile, unstable and magical to be ever used
- see the first note